# Loading indicator while transitioning from view controllers within tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview, dispatch-async

I have tabbarcontroller and within that I have 5 tabs I want to display an overlay containing an activity indicator when tab bar is pressed and the user is waiting for the view to load. The view controllers contain functions that get data from servers so I need to show a loading activity indicator. But when I put it in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewWillAppear` it does not come. So I am trying to do it in tabbarcontroller itself, when an item is selected. But it is not happening. The activityindicator loads after the view has transitioned to the new view. The loading overlay should be immediate.

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item:    UITabBarItem){    

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue((QOS_CLASS_UTILITY), 0)) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(self.view)
        }
    }}  
 public class LoadingOverlay{

       var overlayView = UIView()
       var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

       class var shared: LoadingOverlay {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: LoadingOverlay = LoadingOverlay()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    public func showOverlay(view: UIView) {

        overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
        overlayView.center = view.center
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.7)
        overlayView.clipsToBounds = true
        overlayView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
        activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(overlayView.bounds.width / 2, overlayView.bounds.height / 2)

        overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        view.addSubview(overlayView)

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            }

     public func hideOverlayView() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
    }  }                                                     `
```

Comment: Why dont you have a base class which will show and hide the activity indicator and extend all the classes from this base class which need activity to be shown?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman loadingoverlay is that class, how else would you recommend me to do it.

Comment: LoadingOverlay will be your base class and controllers in which you need activity indicator should extend from LoadingOverlay. Now in LoadingOverlay declare two methods showSpinner and hideSpinner

Comment: If you didnt get my point. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [IJProgressView](https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/IJProgressView) library to show HUD

Usage:
To show the progress view,

```
IJProgressView.shared.showProgressView(view)
```

To hide the progress view,

```
IJProgressView.shared.hideProgressView()
```